# Show that $A=\{x_n : n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{0,1,2\}$. Show that $A$ is compact in $\Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

Define
\begin{align*}
x_n=
\begin{cases}
\frac{n}{n+1}, \qquad \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
\frac{n+1}{n}, \qquad \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}
\qquad \forall n \in \Bbb N.
\end{align*}
Let $A=\{x_n : n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{0,1,2\}$. Show that $A$ is compact in $\Bbb R$.

**Attempt:**
Let $\mathcal{G}=\{G_s:s \in I\}$ be arbitrary open cover of $A$. We want to show that there exists a finite subcover of $\mathcal{G}$.
By assumption, there exists $0 \in I$ such that $1 \in G_0$. Since $G_0$ is open, then there is a real number $\epsilon>0$ such that
$1\in (1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon) \subseteq G_0$. By the Archimedean Principle, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac1N < \epsilon$. Hence, for all $n > N$, we have:

1. $1-\epsilon<x_n=1+\frac{1}{n} < 1+\frac{1}{N} < 1+\epsilon$, if $n$ is even.
2. $1-\epsilon < 1-\frac{1}{N} < 1-\frac{1}{n} < 1-\frac{1}{n+1}=x_n<1+\epsilon$, if $n$ is odd.

Hence, $x_n \in (1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ for all $n > N$.
Now, let $G_1,G_2,G_3,\ldots,G_{N+2}$ be open covers of $0,2,x_1,\ldots,x_N$, respectively.
Then, we have
$$A \subseteq \bigcup_{j=0}^{N+2} G_j,$$
so that $\bigcup_{j=0}^{N+2} G_j$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal{G}$. Since $\mathcal{G}$ was arbitrary, it follows that $A$ is compact.

Is my approach correct? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: By the Heine-Borel theorem, $A$ is compact iff $A$ is closed and bounded. If $x$ is a limit point of $A$, there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_{n_k} \rightarrow x$. Plainly $x_n\rightarrow 1$. Hence $x$ must be $1$.

Comment: @user912011 Showing by definition, not using theorem.

Comment: Forget the theorem. Since $1$ is the limit of $\{x_n\}$, an open set $G$ containing $1$ contains $x_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Hence there are finitely many points in $A\setminus G$. It should be clear now $A$ is compact. I just want to provide you some different approach.

Comment: Oh, pardon me please. Thanks for the different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct.
Well done!

Answer (score 1):

For the second estimate I think you were considering the case where $n$ is odd. In this case $x_n=1-1/(n+1)$. So maybe you can write $$1-\epsilon<1-\frac{1}{N}\leq 1-\frac{1}{n+1}=x_n$$
when $n$ is odd.

Also, I think it would be better to add something like: Clearly, when $n$ is even, we have $1-\epsilon<1+1/n$. (Although it's not necessary, of course.)